# jquery onclick all inputs

Tags: jquery, onclick, this

How would i remove a class from all inputs onClick? I don't want it to remove the class of every input on the page at once when one input is click. I just want the clicked input to be removed of the class. But i want the code to apply to every input tag...if that makes sense...

I'm pretty sure jquery's "this" would be used. I just don't know how to use it.

I'd like it to a remove a specific class, not all classes. so something like this.

```
removeClass("blank_input");
```

Comment: If four people can provide the same answer simultaneously, you obviously didn't do any real research, and this is a trivial task you could have written yourself if you read the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input").click(function(){
   $(this).removeClass("blank_input");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('blank_input');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("blank_input"); 
});
```

Yep, you're right, `this` is involved.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
$('input').click(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("class_name");
});
```